# Where is libpython3.6.dylib?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, py2app

I'm Mac user and I wanted to use py2app, but it couldn't find libpython3.6.dylib. I know that's because of anaconda because it use libpython3.6m.dylib. I want to fix it but I don't know where to find libpython3.6.dylib. Can you help me?